# Value error using relative imports in python

Tags: python, relative-import

I have the following structure of files in my project:

```
Finishing
    Hora a Hora
        .idea
        interface
            __init__.py
            interface.py
            test.py
        utils
            common
                __init__.py
                common.py
            __init__.py
            database_connection.py
    app.py
    __init__.py
```

Inside `database_connection.py` I have sqlite connections to `connect` and `close` connections.

The problem is: inside `test.py` i had tried to import `database_connection.py` functions using the following code:
`from ..utils.database_connection import DatabaseConnection`
but when I try to run the `test.py` I have the following problem:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

How can I import the function correctly?

Comment: I'd suggest not using relative imports. Is there a reason to not using `from utils.database_connection import DatabaseConnection`?

Comment: Does `Project` actually contain an `__init__.py` file? If so, what is your PYTHONPATH set to?

Comment: I intend to use a database to create buttons in the interface with this code. When I finish the interface, app.py will write a log in an other data.db file. That's why I wish to separate things

Comment: How do you run the test.py?

Comment: I'm still developing, so I'm running test.py only, just to check if all functions works properly

Comment: Yes but how - on the terminal? what command are you issuing?